# react/jsx-a11y eslint throws unexpected errors for control/label

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, jsx

This code:

```
      <PopupContent>
        <label htmlFor="popup" style={{ margintop : '0px', marginbottom : '0px' }}>log out</label>
        <button type="button" id="popup" onClick={this.logUserOut} />
      </PopupContent>
```

throws these two errors:

```
 84:9  error  A form label must be associated with a control  jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control
 85:9  error  A control must be associated with a text label  jsx-a11y/control-has-associated-label
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

You don't typically use a  element to label a button. More commonly, the text inside the button serves as its label. Try something along the lines of:

```
<button type="button id="popup" onClick={this.logUserOut}>log out</button>
```

Other options could be any one of the following:

```
<button type="button" id="popup" onClick={this.logUserOut} aria-label="log out"/>
```

or

```
<span id="button-label" style={{ margintop : '0px', marginbottom : '0px' }}>log out</span>
<button type="button" id="popup" onClick={this.logUserOut} aria-labelledby="button-label" />
```

or

```
<button type="button id="popup" onClick={this.logUserOut}>
    <img src="icon.png" alt="log out"/>
</button>
```

or

```
<button type="button id="popup" onClick={this.logUserOut}>
    <span className="off-screen">log out</span>
</button>
```

where the CSS class of .off-screen hides the text off-screen in an accessible way e.g. do not use display: none; or visibility: hidden;

Comment: Thank you for `aria-label`!:)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this rule isn't fully baked: see [Consider adding `jsx-a11y/control-has-associated-label` when it becomes more stable](https://github.com/manovotny/eslint-config-get-off-my-lawn/issues/109)

Answer (score 0):

just add `aria-label` attribute

```
   <PopupContent>
    <label htmlFor="popup" style={{ margintop : '0px', marginbottom : '0px' }}>log out</label>
    <button aria-label="Some label" type="button" id="popup" onClick={this.logUserOut} />
  </PopupContent>
```