# eslint jsx-a11y label must be associated with a control error

Tags: jsx, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, tailwind-ui, jsx-a11y

The `<label>` in this code is being rejected by the [eslint jsx-a11y plugin](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y):

> A form label must be associated with a control. eslint([jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/main/docs/rules/label-has-associated-control.md))

```
<div className="flex items-center">
    <input
        id="filter-mobile-color-1"
        name="color[]"
        value="beige"
        type="checkbox"
        className="h-4 w-4 rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500"
    />
    <label
        htmlFor="filter-mobile-color-1"
        className="ml-3 min-w-0 flex-1 text-gray-500"
    >
        Beige
    </label>
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image: VSCode error]

As far as I can see I am matching the ['sibling' case](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/main/docs/rules/label-has-associated-control.md#case-the-label-is-a-sibling-of-the-control) for that rule:

> In this case, use `htmlFor` and an ID to associate the controls.
>
> ```
> <label htmlFor={domId}>Surname</label>
> <input type="text" id={domId} />
> ```

Comment: It might be a bug in eslint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57619332/327074

Comment: This looks very relevant: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/566

Comment: Ah perhaps it is the airbnb config that requires a stricter rule that the label must wrap the input: **"The input needs to *also* be inside the label to satisfy the stricter form of the rule (which the airbnb config configures, for example)."** [eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y #718 (comment)](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/718#issuecomment-650346255)

Comment: **"A lot of TailwindUI examples use this pattern. It's not a11y-friendly. ☝️ I think TailwindUI should default to nesting elements within `<label>`s."** [#718 (later comment)](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/718#issuecomment-651370283). It is indeed a Tailwind UI component, I got the code from https://tailwindui.com/components/ecommerce/components/category-filters

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it came down to this:

> The input needs to *also* be inside the label to satisfy the stricter form of the rule (which the airbnb config configures, for example).
>
> [eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y #718 (comment)](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/718#issuecomment-650346255)

But at that point I gave up - I did confirm that if I put it inside the label then it stopped giving the error:

```
<div className="flex items-center">
    <label
        htmlFor="filter-mobile-color-1"
        className="ml-3 min-w-0 flex-1 text-gray-500"
    >
        <input
            id="filter-mobile-color-1"
            name="color[]"
            value="beige"
            type="checkbox"
            className="h-4 w-4 rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500"
        />
        Beige
    </label>
</div>
```

I just stopped using the example.